# bash join multiple files with empty replacement (-e option)

Tags: linux, bash, join

I have following code to join multiple files together. It works fine but I want to replace the empty values to 0, so I used -e "0". But it doesn't work.
Any ideas?

```
for k in `ls file?`
do
    if [ -a final.results ]
    then
            join -a1 -a2 -e "0" final.results $k  > tmp.res
            mv tmp.res final.results
    else
            cp $k final.results
    fi

done
```

example:

```
file1: 
a 1 
b 2
file2:
a 1 
c 2
file3:
b 1 
d 2

Results:
a 1 0 1 0
b 2 1 0
c 2
d 2

expected:
a 1 1 0
b 2 0 1
c 0 2 0
d 0 0 2
```

Comment: Don't parse the output of `ls`; just use `for k in file?; do`. Also, quote the expansion of `$k` to protect against special characters in the file name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's poorly documented, but when using `join` the `-e` option only works in conjunction with the `-o` option. The order string needs to be amended each time around the loop. The following code should generate your desired output.

```
i=3
orderl='0,1.2'
orderr=',2.2'
for k in $(ls file?)
do
    if [ -a final.results ]
    then
            join -a1 -a2 -e "0" -o "$orderl$orderr" final.results $k  > tmp.res
            orderl="$orderl,1.$i"
            i=$((i+1))
            mv tmp.res final.results
    else
            cp $k final.results
    fi
done
```

As you can see, it starts to become messy. If you need to extend this much further it might be worth deferring to a beefier tool such as awk or python.

Comment: It is still not quite right...
This is the output of your script:
a 1 1 1 0

b 2 2 0 1

c 2 0 2 0

d 2 0 0 2

Comment: that's probably because you have an existing final.results file. Try removing that first. My output is identical to the one you ask for.

Comment: Yes. With your example final.results, running this script gives  ` a 1 1 1 0 b 2 2 0 1 c 2 0 2 0 d 2 0 0 2 ` as above. Clearly, you need to remove that file before re-running.

Comment: Don't parse the output of `ls`! Use `for k in file?; do` instead.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I agree, but I like to modify the askers code as little as possible to emphasise the salient parts of my answer.

Comment: Please, also spread good practices! This answer will be online for perpetuity and we don't want the next generations to commit errors like this anymore. `;-)`

Answer (score 8):

An aside, the GNU version of join supports `-o auto`. The `-e` and `-o` cause enough frustration to turn people to learning awk. (See also [How to get all fields in outer join with Unix join?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15179262)). As cmh said: it's [not] documented, but when using join the `-e` option only works in conjunction with the `-o` option.

General solution:

```
cut -d ' ' -f1 file? | sort -u > tmp.index
for k in file?; do join -a1 -e '0' -o '2.2' tmp.index $k > tmp.file.$k; done
paste -d " " tmp.index tmp.file.* > final.results
rm tmp*
```

Bonus: how do I compare multiple branches in git?

```
for k in pmt atc rush; do git ls-tree -r $k | cut -c13- > ~/tmp-branch-$k; done
cut -f2 ~/tmp-branch-* | sort -u > ~/tmp-allfiles
for k in pmt atc rush; do join -a1 -e '0' -t$'\t' -11 -22 -o '2.2' ~/tmp-allfiles ~/tmp-branch-$k > ~/tmp-sha-$k; done
paste -d " " ~/tmp-allfiles ~/tmp-sha-* > final.results
egrep -v '(.{40}).\1.\1' final.results # these files are not the same everywhere
```

Comment: I think your first point is less of an aside and more of _the right answer_. It does give the options to `join` that have the desired effect.

Comment: Looking back, this is right before my first Git octopus merge. We compared the three branches until all differences were zero :-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are no duplicate keys in a single file and the keys do not contain whitespace, you could use `gawk` and a sorted glob of files. This approach would be quite quick for large files and would use only a relatively small amount of memory compared to a glob of all of the data. Run like:

```
gawk -f script.awk $(ls -v file*)
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGINFILE {
    c++
}

z[$1]

$1 in a {

    a[$1]=a[$1] FS ($2 ? $2 : "0")
    next
}

{
    for(i=1;i<=c;i++) {
        r = (r ? r FS : "") \
        (i == c ? ($2 ? $2 : "0") : "0")
    }

    a[$1]=r; r=""
    b[++n]=$1
}

ENDFILE {

    for (j in a) {
        if (!(j in z)) {
            a[j]=a[j] FS "0"
        }
    }

    delete z
}

END {

    for (k=1;k<=n;k++) {
        print b[k], a[b[k]]
    }
}
```

Test input / Results of `grep . file*`:

```
file1:a 1 
file1:x
file1:b 2
file2:a 1 
file2:c 2
file2:g
file3:b 1 
file3:d 2
file5:m 6
file5:a 4
file6:x
file6:m 7
file7:x 9
file7:c 8
```

Results:

```
a 1 1 0 4 0 0
x 0 0 0 0 0 9
b 2 0 1 0 0 0
c 0 2 0 0 0 8
g 0 0 0 0 0 0
d 0 0 2 0 0 0
m 0 0 0 6 7 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave up using join and wrote my script in other way

```
keywords=`cat file? | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq | xargs` 
files=`ls file? | xargs`
for p in $keywords
do
   x=`echo $p`
   for k in $files
   do
     if grep -q ^$p $k 
     then
        y=`cat $k | grep ^$p | awk '{print $2}'`
        x=`echo $x $y`  
     else 
       echo $p $k
       x=`echo $x 0`    
     fi
   done
   echo $x >> final.results
done
```