# How to get all fields in outer join with Unix join?

Tags: shell, unix, join, gnu, gnu-coreutils

Suppose that I have two files, `en.csv` and `sp.csv`, each containing exactly two comma-separated records:

`en.csv`:

```
1,dog,red,car
3,cat,white,boat
```

`sp.csv`:

```
2,conejo,gris,tren
3,gato,blanco,bote
```

If I execute

```
join -t, -a 1 -a 2 -e MISSING en.csv sp.csv
```

the output I get is:

```
1,dog,red,car
2,conejo,gris,tren
3,cat,white,boat,gato,blanco,bote
```

Notice that all the missing fields have been collapsed.  To get a "proper" full outer join, I need to specify a format; thus

```
join -t, -a 1 -a 2 -e MISSING -o 0,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.2,2.3,2.4 en.csv sp.csv
```

yields

```
1,dog,red,car,MISSING,MISSING,MISSING
2,MISSING,MISSING,MISSING,conejo,gris,tren
3,cat,white,boat,gato,blanco,bote
```

One drawback of this way to produce a full outer join is that one needs to explicitly specify the format of the final table, which may not be easy to do in programmatic applications (where the identity of the joined tables is known only at runtime).

Recent versions of GNU `join` eliminate this shortcoming by supporting the special format `auto`.  Therefore, with such a version of `join` the last command above could be replaced by the far more general

```
join -t, -a 1 -a 2 -e MISSING -o auto en.csv sp.csv
```

How can I achieve this same effect with versions of `join` that do not support the `-o auto` option?

---

**Background and details**

I have a Unix shell (zsh) script that is designed to processes several CSV flatfiles, and does so by making *extensive* use of GNU `join`'s '-o auto' option.  I need to modify this script so that it can work in environments where the available `join` command does not support the `-o auto` option (as is the case for BSD `join` as well as for older versions of GNU `join`).

A typical use of this option in the script is something like:

```
_reccut () {
    cols="1,$1"
    shift
    in=$1
    shift
    if (( $# > 0 )); then
        join -t, -a 1 -a 2 -e 'MISSING' -o auto \
          <( cut -d, -f $cols $in | sort -t, -k1 ) \
          <( _reccut "$@" )
    else
        cut -d, -f $cols $in | sort -t, -k1
    fi
}
```

I show this example to illustrate that it would be difficult to replace `-o auto` with an explicit format, since the fields to include in this format are not known until runtime.

The function `_reccut` above basically extracts columns from files, and joins the resulting tables along their first column.  To see how `_reccut` in action, imagine that, in addition to the files mentioned above, we also had the file

`de.csv`

```
2,Kaninchen,Grau,Zug
1,Hund,Rot,Auto
```

Then, for example, to display side-by-side column 3 of `en.csv`, columns 2 and 4 of `sp.csv`, and column 3 of de.csv one would run:

```
% _reccut 3 en.csv 2,4 sp.csv 3 de.csv | cut -d, 2-
red,MISSING,MISSING,Rot
MISSING,conejo,tren,Grau
white,gato,bote,MISSING
```

Comment: having had to do exactly what you're talking about for a 1-off project  with Sun4, I think you're stuck with coding your own, or supplying new GNU join as part of your install. Sorry, but good luck.

Comment: I guess I should add, after much messing around, I wound up doing assoc arrays in awk, with much less hassle. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that might or might not work for your data. It approaches the problem by aligning the records within a csv file by line number, i.e. record `2` ends up on line `2`, record `3123` on line number `3123` and so on. Missing records/lines are padded with `MISSING` fields, so the input files would be mangled to look like this:

`en.csv`:

```
1,dog,red,car
2,MISSING,MISSING,MISSING
3,cat,white,boat
```

`de.csv`:

```
1,Hund,Rot,Auto
2,Kaninchen,Grau,Zug
3,MISSING,MISSING,MISSING
```

`sp.csv`:

```
1,MISSING,MISSING,MISSING
2,conejo,gris,tren
3,gato,blanco,bote
```

From there it is easy to cut out the columns of interest and just print them side-by-side using `paste`.

To achieve this, we sort the input files *first* and then apply some stupid `awk` magic:

- If a record appears on their expected line number, print it
- Otherwise, print as many lines containing the number of expected (this is based on the number of fields of the first line in the file, same as what `join -o auto` does) `MISSING` fields until the alignment is correct again
- Not all input files are going to the same number of records, so the maximum is searched for before all of this. Then, more lines with `MISSING` fields are printed until the maximum is hit.

## Code

`reccut.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

get_max_recnum()
{
    awk -F, '{ if ($1 > max) { max = $1 } } END { print max }' "$@"
}

align_by_recnum()
{
    sort -t, -k1 "$1" \
        | awk -F, -v MAXREC="$2" '
            NR==1 { for(x = 1; x < NF; x++) missing = missing ",MISSING" }
            {
                i = NR
                if (NR < $1)
                {
                    while (i < $1)
                    {
                        print i++ missing
                    }
                    NR+=i
                }
            }1
            END { for(i++; i <= MAXREC; i++) { print i missing } }
            '
}

_reccut()
{
    local infiles=()
    local args=( $@ )
    for arg; do
        infiles+=( "$2" )
        shift 2
    done
    MAXREC="$(get_max_recnum "${infiles[@]}")" __reccut "${args[@]}"
}

__reccut()
{
    local cols="$1"
    local infile="$2"
    shift 2

    if (( $# > 0 )); then
        paste -d, \
            <(align_by_recnum "${infile}" "${MAXREC}" | cut -d, -f ${cols}) \
            <(__reccut "$@")
    else
        align_by_recnum "${infile}" "${MAXREC}" | cut -d, -f ${cols}
    fi
}

_reccut "$@"
```

## Run

```
$ ./reccut.sh 3 en.csv 2,4 sp.csv 3 de.csv
red,MISSING,MISSING,Rot
MISSING,conejo,tren,Grau
white,gato,bote,MISSING
```

Comment: Would be nice just to get some feedback on this, does it work for you?