# Join loop on multiple files, filling empty fields

Tags: bash, loops, unix, join

I have 28 files I'd like to join on column 1, keeping all results from both files with each iterative join, and filling empty columns with 0. There are two columns total. The expected input and output for the first 3 files:

*File1*

```
a   1       
b   2       
c   1       
d   4
```

*File2*

```
a   2       
b   3
```

*File3*

```
c   2       
d   2       
e   1
```

*joined*

```
a   1   2   0
b   2   3   0
c   1   0   2
d   4   0   2
e   0   0   1
```

I've written out the entire join using a pipe on my actual files, and it works but is obviously messy. I've shortened it with ellipses here for clarity:

```
join -t $'\t' -a 1 -a 2 -e '0' -o 0 1.2 2.2 -1 1 -2 1 *D3-E-N-1*/*matrix.txt.cut *D3-E-N-2*/*matrix.txt.cut | join -t $'\t' -a 1 -a 2 -e '0' -o 0 1.2 1.3 2.2 -1 1 -2 1 - *D3-E-N-3*/*matrix.txt.cut | join -t $'\t' -a 1 -a 2 -e '0' -o 0 1.2 1.3 1.4 2.2 -1 1 -2 1 - *D3-E-N-4*/*matrix.txt.cut | join -t $'\t' -a 1 -a 2 -e '0' -o 0 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 2.2 -1 1 -2 1 - *D3-E-N-5*/*matrix.txt.cut | ... > final.matrix.txt
```

I know this can be looped to add the new fields, but I'm new to programming and loops are not my forte. I've tried this (from here [bash join multiple files with empty replacement (-e option)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963054/bash-join-multiple-files-with-empty-replacement-e-option)):

```
i=3
orderl='0,1.2'
orderr=',2.2'
for k in UNITAS*/*seq_cut
do
    if [ -a final.results ]
    then
        join -a1 -a2 -e "0" -o "$orderl$orderr" final.results $k  > tmp.res
        orderl="$orderl,1.$i"
        i=$((i+1))
        mv tmp.res final.results
    else
        cp $k final.results
    fi
done
```

which gives me the error

> [: too many arguments
>
> [: too many arguments
>
> cp: overwrite ‘final.results’?

Does anyone have suggestions on a script to recursively join files, or a program better suited for this task?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use R and you can change the desired extension as necessary:

Here are the files I used as an example:

**f1.txt**

```
a 1
b 4
c 6
e 3
```

**f2.txt**

```
c 1
d 4
f 5
z 3
```

**f3.txt**

```
a 1
b 4
c 5
e 7
g 12
```

**R code:**

```
#!/bin/env/Rscript

ext='.ext' #can alter this to desired extension
files <- list.files(pattern=ext) #get name of files in a directory
listOfFiles <- lapply(files, function(x){ read.table(x, row.names=1) } )

#The big reduction of all the files into a table
tbl <- Reduce(function(...) data.frame(merge(..., all = T, by = 0), row.names=1), listOfFiles)

tbl[is.na(tbl)] <- 0 #set all NA vals to 0
colnames(tbl) <- files #set the columns to the corresponding filenames (optional)
tbl #print out the table
```

**Output:**

```
  f1.ext f2.ext f3.ext
a      1      0      1
b      4      0      4
c      6      1      5
d      0      4      0
e      3      0      7
f      0      5      0
g      0      0     12
z      0      3      0
```

Comment: Works great, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am quite amazed that your pipe-line worked; I couldn't get it to work myself. Also, your input-files and output-files do not seem to match. But that aside:

Join will only join two columns: a key and a field.This means that you need to need some way to separate the key from the fields, otherwise you will loose previously joined columns.

example:
f1:

```
a   1
b   2
c   1
d   4
```

f2:

```
a   2
b   3
```

f3:

c    2
   d    2 
   e    1

```
$ join -a1 -a2 -e "0" -t'       ' -o "0,1.2,2.2" f1 f2
a   1   2
b   2   3
c   1   0
d   4   0
$ join -a1 -a2 -e "0" -t'       ' -o "0,1.2,2.2" f1 f2 > f4
$ join -a1 -a2 -e "0" -t'       ' -o "0,1.2,2.2" f4 f3
a   1   0
b   2   0
c   1   2
d   4   2
e   0   1
```

Which is not what you want.

You could change the first tab to ; and join and then change back, but if the later files introduce new keys, it would give you half lines for the keys that are not present in the first file.

Adding a file to the joins with just the keys will create a column wit zeroes which must also be removed.

You probably have some wild-card to list all your files, in my example that could be `f?`, but yours could be `file.*` or `*.cols` etc. Try the wild-card with `ls` to be sure.

So, putting that together:

```
#first make a key-file k0
cat f?  | cut -f1  | sort -u > k0
# change the separator to ';' and back
for f in f? ; do
    sed 's/\t/;/' k0 > t0
    sed 's/\t/;/' $f > t1
    join -a1 -a2 -e "0" -t';' -o "0,1.2,2.2" t0 t1 | sed 's/;/\t/g' > k0
done
# remove the '0' column from the key-file
sed 's/\t0\t/\t/' k0
```

or have a look at awk.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The three files above were just an example, as I actually have many files to join. The command I've written pipes the joins on all files together, each time adding the new fields (1.2 1.3 1.4 ect) so they are not lost. What I need is a loop that increments and adds these for an arbitrary number of files.

Comment: editted the answer to show how to loop over filenames in a wildcard.